# Conjugacy classes of a group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

What is number of conjugacy classes in the permutation group $S_{6}$

I only knows that $o(S_6)=6!$

Comment: Any conjugacy class in a symmetric group is exactly determined by the shape of the cycle decomposition of an element of the class. Does this help?

Comment: Hint : enumerate the number of ordered partitions of $6$.

Comment: I dont know what is cycle decomposition.

Comment: P(6)=11.So no of cojugacy class are 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjugacy classes of $S_n$ is equal to the partition ($p(n)$ is partition function) of $n$. In this case $n=6$ so $p(6)=11$ , hence there are $11$ conjugacy classes for $S_6$